# Volume integration with a condition

Tags: numerical-integration, trigonometry

I have a set of parameters $x_1, \dots x_4 \in (0,1)$. I want to find the volume of the subregion of this 4d cube satisfying
$$\sin^{-1}(x_1)+ \dots +\sin^{-1}(x_4) > \frac{3\pi}{2}$$

I've tried using a simple

```
NIntegrate[ If[ArcSin[x1] + ArcSin[x2] + ArcSin[x3] + ArcSin[x4] > (3 Pi)/2, 1, 
  0], {x4, 0, 1}, {x3, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}, {x1, 0, 1}]
```

However I get numerical lamentations.
If I solve for one of the $x_i$ and put $x_i = \sin(\frac{3\pi}{2}-\sum_{j\neq i} \sin^{-1}{x_j})$ as a lower limit in its integral, I lose information by taking the sine ($\sin(x)$ is two-to-one for $x<2\pi$) and the $x_i$ integral can move beyond its range of validity.

Is there an elegant way to this without many If/else statements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Using [`If`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If.html)

```
vol1 = NIntegrate[
  If[ArcSin[x1] + ArcSin[x2] + ArcSin[x3] + ArcSin[x4] > 3 Pi/2, 1, 0], {x4, 
   0, 1}, {x3, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}, {x1, 0, 1}, MinRecursion -> 9, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 20, 
  Method -> {"AdaptiveQuasiMonteCarlo", "RandomSeed" -> 1234}]

(* 0.00076851819200000000000 *)
```

Using [`Boole`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Boole.html)

```
vol2 = NIntegrate[
  Boole[ArcSin[x1] + ArcSin[x2] + ArcSin[x3] + ArcSin[x4] > 3 Pi/2], {x4, 0, 
   1}, {x3, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}, {x1, 0, 1}, MinRecursion -> 9, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 20, 
  Method -> {"AdaptiveQuasiMonteCarlo", "RandomSeed" -> 1234}]

(* 0.00076851819200000000000 *)
```

Using [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html)

```
vol3 = NIntegrate[
  Piecewise[{{1, 
     ArcSin[x1] + ArcSin[x2] + ArcSin[x3] + ArcSin[x4] > 3 Pi/2}}], {x4, 0, 
   1}, {x3, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}, {x1, 0, 1}, MinRecursion -> 9, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 20, 
  Method -> {"AdaptiveQuasiMonteCarlo", "RandomSeed" -> 1234}]

(* 0.00076851819200000000000 *)

vol1 == vol2 == vol3

(* True *)
```

Comment: Why the difference? The code m[t_] := RegionMeasure[
  ImplicitRegion[
   ArcSin[x1] + ArcSin[x2] + ArcSin[x3] + ArcSin[t] - (3*Pi)/2 >= 0 &&
     x1 >= 0 && x1 <= 1 && x2 >= 0 && x2 <= 1 && x3 >= 0 && 
    x3 <= 1, {x1, x2, x3}]]; NIntegrate[Evaluate[m[t]], {t, 0, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 5, 
 PrecisionGoal -> 5, WorkingPrecision -> 12] performs $0.000835762369747 $.

Comment: @user64494 - I cannot reproduce your results. Running your code causes my kernel to quit. I am running version 12.0 on a Mac.

Comment: @BobHanlon Very interesting solution ideas!  I tried to give another solution way using `RegionMeasure`:  `reg = ImplicitRegion[
  ArcSin[x4] + ArcSin[x3] + ArcSin[x2] + ArcSin[x1] > (3 \[Pi])/2 && 
   0 <= x4 <= 1 && 0 <= x3 <= 1 && 0 <= x2 <= 1 && 0 <= x1 <= 1, {x4, 
   x3, x2, x1}]`, `RegionMeasure[reg]` but it doesn't evaluate. Any idea why not?

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann: So did I with the same result. After that I applied Cavalieri's principle. Now I tried to reproduce my result.

Comment: @user64494 Mysterious!

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann:: Here is a light weight approach which succeeds Clear["Global`*"]; 
m[t_] := RegionMeasure[
  DiscretizeRegion[
   ImplicitRegion[
    ArcSin[x1] + ArcSin[x2] + ArcSin[x3] + ArcSin[t] - (3*Pi)/2 >= 0 &&
      x1 >= 0 && x1 <= 1 && x2 >= 0 && x2 <= 1 && x3 >= 0 && 
     x3 <= 1, {x1, x2, x3}]]];
NIntegrate[Evaluate[m[t]], {t, 0, 1}, AccuracyGoal -> 2, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 2, WorkingPrecision -> 12] // AbsoluteTiming  $ \{13.9241,0.000830119592627\}$ The executed nb on demand through Dropbox.

Comment: @user64494 Thanks, I tried your code and got several error messages, after 80s the result! You seem to have a power-cpmputer ;-)

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann: Rather warnings. After that  it works.Try Table[m[t],{t,0,1,0.1}]. Waiting for your reply. PS. My comp is 9 years old.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon: How about my modified code?

Comment: @user64494 - I get four warning messages (two each of "unable to discretize the region" and "not a correctly specified region") and the result `{76.267, 0.000802141379906}`

Answer (score 0):

Making use of [Cavalieri's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri%27s_principle), one obtains

```
m[t_] := RegionMeasure[DiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[ArcSin[x1] + ArcSin[x2] + ArcSin[x3] + ArcSin[t] - 
(3*Pi)/2 >= 0 &&
 x1 >= 0 && x1 <= 1 && x2 >= 0 && x2 <= 1 && x3 >= 0 && 
x3 <= 1, {x1, x2, x3}]]]
NIntegrate[Evaluate[m[t]], {t, 0, 1},AccuracyGoal -> 2,PrecisionGoal ->2, WorkingPrecision->12]//AbsoluteTiming
```

> $ \{13.9241,0.000830119592627\}$